# executing scalar against insert statement

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to get the id for the last record that I have insert into the database table through my asp.net website.
My insert statment is a stored procedure, I have tried using the scalar function but it is giving me this Specified cast is not valid.

This is the insert statement that I am using:

```
@ClientID varchar(250),
@BType varchar(250),
@CIP varchar(50),
@Sess varchar(500),
@LoggedIn int,
@LoggedInTime datetime

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblSession ( ClientID, BType, CIP, Sess, LoggedIn, LoggedInTime) VALUES ( @ClientID, @BType, @CP,@Sess, @LoggedIn, @LoggedInTime) 
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

And the method that I am calling:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = DBConnection.getConnection())
 {
    string sql = "Add";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@ClientID ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@BType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bt;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CIP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cip;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Sess", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = s;
    command.Parameters.Add("@LoggedIn", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LoggedIn;
    command.Parameters.Add("@LoggedInTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = session.LoggedInTime;

    int x;
    x = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    return x;
 }
```

please any help is much appreiciate it

Comment: Does the command.ExecuteScalar() return anything? If so, what type is it?

Comment: Better to use an output param or returns value; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: the commad.execute scallar return 0

Comment: user clientid varchar you convert to int try to string type

Answer (score 1):

Create an output parameter in the stored procedure and in the C# code, and simply executeNonQuery

Answer (score 0):

I found an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which i think can help you, because it seems to solve a situation like yours. In the example it uses just a query and not a stored procedure, but maybe could help. The scalar query always return a value or NULL if there is nothing to return. Are you sure your insert is working? Maybe it is returning NULL because your insert failed.

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
    Int32 newProdID = 0;
    string sql =
        "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return (int)newProdID;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I´m absolutly not sure if I understand your problem, but the call should be

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i need to retrieve the id of the last inserted record. and commad.executeNonQuery does not return anything.

Comment: No ExecuteScalar is right to return a single value back. ExecuteNonQuery would not return the key value.